# Binding for selected item in select box not sticking

Tags: knockout.js

I've got a nested collection... collection of objects (LearningPath) and each has a collection (LearningItems) within it. In the UI I've bound a table for all the LearningPaths, then a SELECT box for each LearningPath's LearningIUtems. When I select an item, the selected item always goes back to the caption item. It's almost like it isn't setting the value of my selected item.

Here's what the objects and view model looks like:

```
// namespace
var CPT = CPT || {};

// entities
CPT.LearningItem = function (liId, liTitle, liDescription, liType, liUrl) {
  this.id = liId;
  this.title = liTitle;
  this.description = liDescription;
  this.itemType = liType;
  this.url = liUrl;
};

CPT.LearningPath = function (lpId, lpTitle, lpDescription, lpPublishDate, lpPublishedBy) {
  this.id = lpId;
  this.title = lpTitle;
  this.description = lpDescription;
  this.pubDate = lpPublishDate;
  this.pubBy = lpPublishedBy;
  this.status = "";
  this.learingItems = ko.observableArray();

  if (this.pubDate !== null)
    this.status = "Published";
  else
    this.status = "Unpublished";
};

// view model
CPT.ViewModel = function () {
  this.selectedLearningItem = ko.observable();
  this.learningPaths = ko.observableArray();
};
```

Here's the binding:

```
var learningPathsViewModel;

// This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a context object which is needed to use the SharePoint object model
$(document).ready(function () {
  // setup view model
  learningPathsViewModel = CPT.ViewModel.Init();
});
```

And here's the select box...

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Learning Items</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: learningPaths">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: title"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: status"></td>
      <td>
        <select data-bind="optionsCaption: 'Select to view details...',
                            options: learingItems,
                            optionsText: 'title', 
                            value: learningPathsViewModel.selectedLearningItem">
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  <div class="displayBox"
    data-bind="with: selectedLearningItem">
  <h2>Learning Paths</h2>
    Selected item: (id:<span data-bind="text: id" />) <span data-bind="text: title" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectedLearningItem` property should be inside `CPT.LearningPath` object. Because in your implementation there is the same property for storing selected values from each row.

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/w72bn/

Comment: OK, that helps... but then that presents another challenge: I have a detail view outside of the table for the selected items... I'd want only one item selectable in the table so if you select from box A and then box B, A's goes back to the default. Then I'd need to update the detail view. I've updated the HTML in my original question